# My Player Pref float .tostring is not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a player pref float called "overallTime", which stores the Player's Highscore as a float. Displaying the float itself works fine but I want it to be displayed like this: mm:ss:fff. For that I'm using ".ToString(@"mm:ss:fff")". This has already worked with other variables but with this one.

this one doesnt work:
[this is what the besttimeText writes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ash63.jpg)

```
                Debug.Log(PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("overallTime")); //this displays the float itself just not formatted
                bestTimeText.text = "Best Time: " + PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("overallTime").ToString(@"mm\:ss\:fff"); //this does not work
```

[this is the timer with the same toString code but this works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9d3G.jpg)
But this one does:

```
        timerText.text = time.ToString(@"mm\:ss\:fff");
```

Any ideas for a solution are much appreciated.

Comment: "Displaying the float itself works fine but I want it to be displayed like this: mm:ss:fff" I can't understand what this means. Suppose the float has a value of `1.0`. What should be the result, and **why** - according to what logic? "I have a player pref float called "overallTime", which stores the Player's Highscore as a float. " - is it a time, or a score?

Comment: you havent included enough but normally a timer is made of time.. so is designed to be split into h/m/s etc a float is a float, it is just that.

Answer (score 0):

Try splitting the minute and second into separate variables and do it like this:

```
timerText.text = $({mm}":"{ss})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But this sadly didnt work. However I found a solution. I will post it here.

Comment: Sorry that it didn't work, but I'm happy you found the solution!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution! The normal .toString(@"mm:ss:fff") doesnt just work. I have to use this:

```
bestTimeText.text = "Best Time: " + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("overallTime")).ToString(@"mm\:ss\:fff");
```

this displays the float in the correct formatting. Thanks for all the comments and answers!